# Generics - Cannot implicity convert when T constrained to be interface but fine when T an abstract class

Tags: c#

In the below code when T: Entity the compiler is happy.

When T:IEntity I get a "cannot implicitly convert error"

I don't understand why?

```
public abstract class BaseImplementation<T>: ISomeInterface<T> where T: Entity
{
    public abstract T[] GetEntities();

    IEntity[] ISomeInterface.GetEntities()
    {
        return GetEntities();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
where T : class, IEntity
```

covariance for arrays works only for reference types. For example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx):

> For any two **reference-types** A and B, if an implicit reference conversion (Section 6.1.4) or explicit reference conversion (Section 6.2.3) exists from A to B, then the same reference conversion also exists from the array type A[R] to the array type B[R],

To give an example:

```
public class Entity : IEntity { }
public struct StructEntity : IEntity { }
```

and then:

```
IEntity[] ent1 = new Entity[5];
IEntity[] ent2 = new StructEntity[5];
```

The second line gives a compilation error.